# 2D Hidden Object Silhouette Shader

Tags: shaders, glsl, graphic-effects, jogl

Right now I am not using any depth information in my engine, but I just found out that it would be neat to be able to render the silhouette of important game objects that are "behind" something with a shader, though I am quite at a loss how to do this in a 2D scene with little to no depth information. I will propably have to use depth information for something like that, but I am not quite sure how.

I guess the abstract concept would be:

```
zn = depth of pixel that should be rendered
zc = depth of pixel at current position in some sort of buffer
if(zn < zc)
    render pixel with a "silhouette" color
else
    render pixel with it's intended color
```

Is this a proof of concept I can follow in my next few workhours?
How can I use and access stuff like the Z buffer of the current framebuffer in the shader?

As an example, I most recently saw this in Titan Souls:

[image: left half is obscured, right half is rendered normally]

Also remember that I am thinking 2D only, so application of the painter's algorithm might or might not be desirable.

EDIT: So right now, from comments and such, I got the following proof of concept:

```
activate stencil mechanism to set stencil
render obscuing objects
deactivate stencil
render scene, using painter's algorithm or depth checks to obscure
activate stencil mechanism to check weather or not something got rendered within the stencil area
render important objects again, using a different fragment shader to render pixels within the stencil as a dark shadow
```

amirite?

Comment: Wanting to sample THE depth buffer (not A depth buffer) usually indicates a design problem. Additionally, sampling THE depth buffer is impossible. While it is possible that early-z will calculate every depth value before the pixel shader is invoked, the values are not written until after the pixel shader completes, making them defacto unsampleable.

Comment: There would probably be work-arounds to the implications but, in the end, you cannot bind a buffer as both a render target(or depth buffer) and a shader resource, at the same time. You *can* copy the previous frame's depth-buffer into a shader resource but that, specifically, is the design flaw indicator.

Comment: If this indeed does not work, how is that very common effect created then? Even in 3D games, if the view to important objects is obscured, you can most often see a shadow / an outlining of the object on the obscuring object.

Comment: I would have to guess that they used the stencil buffer. It is extremely configurable; it can count the number of times a pixel is written, the number of times a pixel fails the depth test (gets clipped), etc., etc. For that image, draw the player sprite first, using depth as usual, but also writing 1's to the stencil anywhere a pixel gets colored. Then, render as usual with the stencil disabled. Finally, render a full-screen quad with alpha-blending active and the stencil set to only render where there are 1's. Tint the existing color any way you'd like.

Comment: Sorry I wrote this in DirectX; I missed the tags. The concept will be the same, although you will need to say potayto instead of my potahto.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you could render silhouetteable objects last, and write 1's to the stencil buffer only when pixels fail the depth test. Then, render (such as your image appears to be) a flat color anywhere there are 1's in the stencil (using opaque shading (probably)). This is basically what you were suggesting in your proof, except possible.

Comment: Before I go into the deep depths of the web and find out: Where does OpenGL manage this stencil buffer? Is one associated to each framebuffer (including the main buffer) or do I need to create a seperate one for each framebuffer I am rendering to, having to clean all that up also on program exit (I am also right now starting to write cleanup code)

Comment: Also in OpenGL, each framebuffer has it's own depth and stencilbuffer (can be linked)

Comment: It is entirely valid to write to more than one RT while sharing a single depth/stencil. Writing the same depth to multiple depth buffers is not desirable. Also, the stencil typically consumes a "channel" within the depth buffer, reducing it's precision. DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT vs. DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT

Comment: Also keep in mind that, even though the stencil is swizzled into the depth buffer, you can still ClearDepthStencilView() them independently using the correct CLEAR_FLAGS. (I know, sorry it's DirectX) This lets you reuse a single depth buffer for entirely different purposes while preserving the stencil for a future pass.

Comment: Specifically, I render my Interface components ("2D") first, writing 1's to the stencil. Then, I clear the Interface depth buffer and draw the World to different sets of RT's using the same depth buffer each time. Anywhere that stencil is 1 is occluded by the interface, so I don't even bother drawing those pixels. When you look at my World RT, there are Transparent holes in it.

Comment: I added a visual to my answer and will follow you to chat if you need additional assistance.

Comment: You were pretty much looking for the same thing I was, and I also found a solution using GLSL. I answered my own question here - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103365/glsl-2d-silhouette/103427#103427 - It's done using libGDX, but the solution should be adaptable to any engine with the same capabilities.

Comment: Hi salbeira, did you solve? Do you still need help?

Comment: I think I did though I still did not write a test to check weather or not I was right.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the stencil buffer:**

When writing:

```
dsDesc.StencilEnable = true;
dsDesc.StencilReadMask = D3D11_DEFAULT_STENCIL_READ_MASK;
dsDesc.StencilWriteMask = D3D11_DEFAULT_STENCIL_WRITE_MASK;
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS; //Always Pass
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR; //Increment
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //Doesn't matter
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR; //Increment
```

When reading:

```
dsDesc.StencilEnable = true;
dsDesc.StencilReadMask = D3D11_DEFAULT_STENCIL_READ_MASK;
dsDesc.StencilWriteMask = D3D11_DEFAULT_STENCIL_WRITE_MASK; //Or 0 to disable all writes
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_GREATER; //Only greather than REF
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //No writes
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //No writes
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //No writes
```

Render the scene as usual with the stencil buffer active, incrementing.

```
g_d3dContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(stencilWriteState, 0x00);
Draw(...);
```

Then, render a full-screen quad, using the stencil buffer as a reference to apply the pixel shader effect only to pixels with stencil(>1).

```
g_d3dContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(stencilReadState, 0x01);
```

**If you know ahead of time, which "important objects" are behind others:**
Render them separately, and first, with the stencil active. Then disable the stencil for the remainder of the (occluding) objects. Finally, render the full-screen quad to apply the shader to pixels with stencil(>0).

```
g_d3dContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(stencilReadState, 0x00);
```

Example usage:
[image: example stencil usage]

Comment: OP seems to be using OpenGL, see the glsl and jogl tags.

Comment: @Eejin, I missed that. Any chance of you translating for me?

Comment: As a sprite is a rectangle, can I also affect the stencil buffer with some kind of alpha test so that I can only affect the stencil buffer on pixels that were actually rendered, instead of having a 0 alpha value.

Comment: glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST); glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.05); //reject any pixels with alpha less than 0.05